# Error in Gatling maven plugin

Tags: scala, maven, gatling, scala-gatling

I´m using gatling-maven-plugin to run some Performance test.
I just follow the official documentation http://gatling.io/docs/2.2/extensions/maven_plugin/

I have this configuration

```
<!--PERFORMANCE TEST-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<disableCompiler>true</disableCompiler>-->
                <configFolder>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</configFolder>
                <dataFolder>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/data</dataFolder>
                <resultsFolder>${project.basedir}/target/gatling/results</resultsFolder>
                <bodiesFolder>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/bodies</bodiesFolder>
                <simulationsFolder>${project.basedir}/src/test/scala/performance/</simulationsFolder>
                <runDescription>This-is-the-run-description</runDescription>
                <simulationClass>${project.basedir}\src\test\scala\performance\TillScenario</simulationClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

it´s complaining because

```
error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/AnnotationInfos$ErroneousAnnotation$
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$class.newTyper(Typers.scala:100)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.newTyper(Global.scala:463)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.<init>(Namers.scala:58)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$NormalNamer.<init>(Namers.scala:50)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$class.newNamer(Namers.scala:51)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.newNamer(Global.scala:463)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$namerFactory$$anon$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:43)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$applyPhase$1.apply$mcV$sp(Global.scala:441)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.withCurrentUnit(Global.scala:432)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:441)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:399)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:399)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:750)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1202)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:399)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1500)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1487)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1482)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1580)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:32)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:23)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:51)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Main.process(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at sbt.compiler.RawCompiler.apply(RawCompiler.scala:33)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:146)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
        at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:344)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
        at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:344)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInterfaceJar(IncrementalCompiler.scala:58)
        at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler$.compilerInterface(Compiler.scala:148)
        at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler$.create(Compiler.scala:53)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$delayedInit$body.apply(ZincCompiler.scala:147)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler$.main(ZincCompiler.scala:36)
        at io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler.main(ZincCompiler.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
        at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.reflect.internal.AnnotationInfos$ErroneousAnnotation$
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 54 more
```

And If I add this line in the configuration

```
<disableCompiler>true</disableCompiler>
```

it´s complaint because cannot find the my simulationClass

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The requested class 'path\TillScenario' can not be found in the classpath or does not extends Simulation.
```

Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure whether you have added the [Scala Maven Plugin](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin) or not after disabling the `gatling-maven-plugin`, but this might explain the second error, as described [here](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2/extensions/maven_plugin/#coexisting-with-scala-maven-plugin). You should compile your `Simulation` classes somehow, either via the Gatling plugin or the Scala plugin.

As for the first error, it looks like a dependency mismatch issue. Make sure you are using the binary compatible versions of Gatling dependencies as well as Scala ones.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Seems like the version 2.2.4 has some issues. I downgread to 2.2.1 and works

Comment: Obviously broken maven download

Answer (score 1):

I resolved by updating scala library version from 2.11.6 to 2.11.8

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
```